# Uncaught TypeError when trying to extend dojo widget "dojox/timing"

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to extend the dojox/timing widget and add functionality. I wanted to add to it so it can check if an end time is set and if it is then end the process once it reaches that time.

With the code I have written I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'endTime' in undefined

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang", "dojox/timing"], function(lang, timing) {
    lang.extend(timing, {
        endTime: 0,
        setEndTime: function(newEndTime) {
            this.endTime = newEndTime;
        },
        printEndTime: function() {
            console.log("End time: " + this.endTime);
        }
    });
    var t = new timing.Timer(1000);
    t.onTick = function() {
        console.info("One second elapsed");
    };
    t.onStart = function() {
        console.info("Starting timer");
    };
    t.printEndTime();
    t.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is timing itself is not a class, you have to extend the class which is Timer

```
 lang.extend(timing.Timer, .......
```